# How to select rows with conditions based on other columns

Tags: r, data.table

Given the data.table,

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table(Year=c(rep(2014,1,8), 2015, 2014, 2014), no=c(111,111,111,222,222,333,333,444,555,666,666), type=c('a','b','c','a','a','a','f','a', 'a', 'c','f'))
```

return,

```
    Year  no type
 1: 2014 111    a
 2: 2014 111    b
 3: 2014 111    c
 4: 2014 222    a
 5: 2014 222    a
 6: 2014 333    a
 7: 2014 333    f
 8: 2014 444    a
 9: 2015 555    a
10: 2014 666    c
11: 2014 666    f
```

I would like to filter out any `no` that does not contain both 'a' and others ('b', 'c', and etc.).  That means, id 222, 444, and 666 will be filtered out. Note that `no` 555 was filtered out because of Year 2015.

The return I expect is

```
   Year  no type
1: 2014 111    a
2: 2014 111    b
3: 2014 111    c
4: 2014 333    a
5: 2014 333    f
```

Then, we use `unique` to finally get `no` 111 and 333 as our final result.

I have tried the following:

```
setkey(dt, Year)
dt1 <- dt[J(2014)][,.(type=unique(type)), by = no]
unique(na.omit(merge(dt1[type=='a'],dt1[type!='a'], by = 'no', all = T))[,no])
```

However, I think this code is not efficient.
Could you please give me suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
dt[Year == 2014, if("a" %in% type & uniqueN(type) > 1) .SD, by = no]
#    no Year type
#1: 111 2014    a
#2: 111 2014    b
#3: 111 2014    c
#4: 333 2014    a
#5: 333 2014    f
```

Or, since you are only interested in unique `no`s:

```
dt[Year == 2014, "a" %in% type & uniqueN(type) > 1, by = no][(V1), no]
#[1] 111 333
```

In case there may be `NA`s in your type column that you don't want to count as other values, you could modify it to:

```
dt[Year == 2014, "a" %in% type & uniqueN(na.omit(type)) > 1, by = no][(V1), no]
#[1] 111 333
```

Comment: what is `.SD` after `if` ?

Comment: `.SD` is the subsetted data.table (per group)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `any`

```
res <- dt[Year==2014, if(any(type=="a") & any(type!="a")) .SD, no]
res
#    no Year type
#1: 111 2014    a
#2: 111 2014    b
#3: 111 2014    c
#4: 333 2014    a
#5: 333 2014    f

unique(res$no)
#[1] 111 333
```

---

The same methodology can be applied with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(no) %>% 
   filter(any(type=="a") & any(type!="a") & Year==2014)
```